# Problems with meteor/react, getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Just starting web development I'll try and give all relevant information, to start I'm using web storm(IDE) and meteor react. Now I was follow along a tutorial and can't figure out why the below code isn't working. Specifically the reactDOM.render portion.

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Personal Project</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div id = "root"></div>
</body>
```

JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function formatName(user) {
    return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const user = {
    firstName: 'Justin',
    lastName: 'Schneider'
};

const element = (
    <h1> Hello, {formatName(user)}!</h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementsById('root')
);
```

When I try locally hosting the above, nothing happens besides the title being set to "Personal Project". Any help would be appreciated and as well as debugging tips. Please keep in mind Web storm, Meteor, and React are all new to me.

Comment: Have you tried following the official Meteor/React tutorial? You need to render the React app within the Meteor startup callback: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in method name:

```
document.getElementsById('root')
```

It should be:

```
document.getElementById('root')
```